# Can I convert non UTF-8 encoding CSV file downloading from web into UTF-8 encoding in Rstudio?

Tags: r, csv, encoding, utf-8

I want to import a CSV file from web. The CSV file is an EUC-KR encoding file, and there are some Korean characters in the CSV file.

When I tried this:

```
x <- "www.google.com/abcdefg.csv"
read.csv(x, header=T)
```

I got this error message:

```
Error in make.names(col.names, unique = True) :
 invalid multibyte string at '<b3><af>￥
```

I know that I can convert the CSV file with Text Editor like Notepad++.

*But I want to import some non UTF-8 encoding data from web in Rstudio not using the Text Editor.*

I also tried this:

```
x <- "www.google.com/abcdefg.csv"
read.csv(x, header=T,encoding="UTF-8")
```

but I still got the same error message. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: There is a `fileEncoding=` parameter where you should specify the encoding of the file.

Answer (score 1):

When reading the csv, you should state the encoding of the input. So try replacing UTF-8 with the encoding of your file.